# 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object is not callable while copying M2M relation

Tags: python, django, m2m

I have this relation defined in x\research.py file.

```
research_groups = models.ManyToManyField(ResearchGroup, related_name='researchs', blank=True,
                                             through='ResearchResearchGroups')
```

Then i want copy it to y\research.py file with

```
research.research_groups.set(Research.research_groups.all())
```

And while im trying to use it i get

> 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object is not callable

How can i handle assigning m2m relation to another place?

Comment: What is `Research.research_groups.all()` supposed to do?

Comment: Due to getting error "'ManyToManyDescriptor' object is not iterable" i thought that it will solve the problem, but when you asked your question using it seems useless and even dummy... But while m2m is not iterable can i assign it without using loops?